# How can I use Angular.js in a Google Apps Script served HTML site?

Tags: google-apps-script, angularjs

Is it possible to include and use Angular.js as part of a web app served using HtmlService in Google Apps Script or will caja sanitise it out?

Additionally will it be possible to use Angular within the HtmlService templating method within Apps Script itself?

Comment: I have tried - it seems crippled - Corey's Answer seems to confirm it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use angular with following change in your appscript file.

```
var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('myPage')
  .setTitle('My Title');
ui.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

Comment: Indeed. As per the comment I added to my own question.

Comment: This is not currently working for me. Let me know if you need anything else. How is your html ? could  you share it?

Answer (score 4):

This is not currently possible, although it may be supported in the future.

Comment: There is actually an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3289) requesting this feature.

Comment: And now it is possible under the `IFRAME` sandbox

Comment: I have been using this in production for several months now. It works fine.