# Angular JS in Google Apps Script

Tags: angularjs, google-apps-script, google-caja

Does Angular JS will be supported by Google Apps Script?  I am able to use external Library like jQuery, UnderscoreJS but not Angular JS?

Any idea about when CAJA will support Angular JS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use Angular.js in a Google Apps Script served HTML site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737033/how-can-i-use-angular-js-in-a-google-apps-script-served-html-site)

Comment: I just tried doing this and it looks like it generally works (with the non-minified version), but for me -- I can't seem to use services/directives. Can anyone else do it?

Comment: This is now possible in iframe mode https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#restrictions_in_iframe_mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Apps Script supports Angular JS . You need to use the full version (not minified) . There are some issues on firefox, but works fine mostly.

You can use angular with following change in your appscript file.

```
var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('myPage')
  .setTitle('My Title');
ui.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

Comment: This recent update on the issue tracker says it doesn't. https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3289.  But I didn't test actually.

Comment: I have a angular based running add on listed in market place(It has been listed for almost a year), but it only works in chrome , opera.