# How do I make AngularJS work in Google Apps Script?

Tags: angularjs, google-apps-script

I am currently following this tutorial:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-real-time-scheduling-app-using-angularjs-and-firebase#connecting-to-and-using-firebase, but it is not working as I have it in Google Apps Script.

I am trying to use `AngularJS` in `Apps Scripts`.  However, the documented fixes to make `AngularJS` work is documented to use the following line of code:

```
var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('myPage')
  .setTitle('My Title');
ui.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

Source: [Angular JS in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610315/angular-js-in-google-apps-script)

But I am not sure where to put this in my `Code.gs` file?  I have a `function.doGet`, so does it go in there?

Right now, my `Code.gs` is as follows:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`HtmlService.createOutputFromFile(...)` returns an instance of the [`HtmlOutput`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output) class, which has the `setSandboxMode(..)` method. Assuming that you have a file "index.html" in your Apps Script project, your code is correct:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

`doGet` is the method called by the Apps Script runtime when user navigates to your app's URL, and it should return the fully formed HTML that you want to render (which can include references to externally hosted js, css, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The tutorial mentions, "We will also be pulling in Bootstrap to handle some styling duties."  How do I implement the `bootstrap` into Google Scripts?  Do I need to download the `style.css` file from the `bootstrap`, and then manually enter it with the <style> ENTER STYLE.CSS CODE HERE </style>?

Comment: In your html markup, you can import an css files, or <script src=''> any js files. The [scotch.io tutorial] demonstrates it:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.0/journal/bootstrap.min.css" />`